# Reading csv with Python breaks on square bracket

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv that I'm trying to read with Python, which has lines that look like the following:

```
10x org il,"["Modiin, Israel"]","["no current price posted"]","["Modiin: no current size posted"]","{ "Python Bootcamp": {"Price: ","["http://www.10x.org.il/"]","[{ "j": 31.9077, "C": 35.0076 }]"
```

but it breaks on the first square bracket of this: `"[{ "j": 31.9077, "C": 35.0076 }]"` with the error message `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I am using the following python to read the file:

```
import csv

with open('programming_bootcamps_csv.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         print(row["campName"])
```

I have been reading through some documents on why a square bracket would break this, and haven't come to any conclusions on what the issue is or how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried using csv.reader() instead of DictReader?

Comment: Look at the code highlighting that SO automatically applied: one of the commas has quotes around it, inverting the quoted status of the rest of the content. That makes for a poorly-formed CSV file.

Comment: I popped that line into a triple-quoted string and `count('"')` returned `27`. Check the file, make sure all quotes are matched, and so on.

Comment: I will try to reformat the csv. I took an excel file and simply saved it as a csv, but it had too many `"` so I changed double and triple `"` to single quotes

Comment: try keeping the quotes as the original file specifies.

Comment: "Too many" according to what/whom?

Comment: The name of the column

Comment: "Too many" meaning that it took the row as it is shown and added 2 or three quotes in place of every single quote

Comment: It looks like the following when I convert it as-is: `10x org il,"[""Modiin, Israel""]","[""no current price posted""]","[""Modiin: no current size posted""]","{ ""Python Bootcamp"": {""Price: ","[""http://www.10x.org.il/""]","[{ ""j"": 31.9077, ""C"": 35.0076 }]"`

Comment: unfortunately, csv module will not let you use more than a single character for either `quotechar` or `delimiter`.  This is for performance reasons I'm sure, but if you can't clean your data you will have to write a custom csv parser.

Comment: I didn't ask what you meant by "too many"; I asked who or what came to that conclusion. Did you try to generate and use the file and then Excel or Python gave you an error? Or did you look at the generated output and decide on your own to change it manually before parsing it?

Comment: Can you provide the column headers and the raw data in your question please.

Comment: Thanks @GraemeStuart the file is actually ok if I leave the double quotes, I just need to call each column with quotes inside of single-quotes: `for row in reader: print(row['"Locations"'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't manually pre-process data unless *absolutely* necessary

I have reconstructed your data according to the comments as follows:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
10x org il,"[""Modiin, Israel""]","[""no current price posted""]","[""Modiin: no current size posted""]","{ ""Python Bootcamp"": {""Price: ","[""http://www.10x.org.il/""]","[{ ""j"": 31.9077, ""C"": 35.0076 }]"
```

Now everything works as expected.

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         for key, value in row.items():
            print "{}: {}".format(key, value)
```

output:

```
col6: ["http://www.10x.org.il/"]
col7: [{ "j": 31.9077, "C": 35.0076 }]
col4: ["Modiin: no current size posted"]
col5: { "Python Bootcamp": {"Price:
col2: ["Modiin, Israel"]
col3: ["no current price posted"]
col1: 10x org il
```

It looks like the curious format is a broken mixture of json and csv. Your curly brackets don't match up and there is no consistency. Since it looks like it was generated automatically I would strongly suggest fixing the data format upstream in the program that generated the file.

However, if you can't fix the data upstream then further processing should be simple, possibly using `json.loads()` or if necessary with brute force.

Comment: "Since it looks like it was generated automatically" - I think it initially was, and then the OP decided it was wrong and changed it.

Comment: Indeed. A data crime. Perhaps the original file was json?

Comment: Who knows. I think the moral of the story is not to vandalize your own data (a data crime, indeed :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DictReader, write your own parser.

```
def dict_reader(fn, header=None):
    for line in open(fn):
        row = []
        while line:
            field,_, line = line.partition(",")
            while field.startswith('"["') and not field.endswith('"]"'):
                rest, _, line = line.partition(",")
                field += rest
            row.append(field)
        if header is None:
            header = row
            continue
        yield dict(zip(header, row))
```

Comment: This is a sure way to create difficulties. It would be far better to go back and generate a properly-formatted CSV rather than attempt to hack a broken one back together with duct tape.

Comment: OK..  use DictWriter to put the output of this function right back into a file?

Comment: The input to the function shouldn't be broken in the first place. The problem here is a malformed CSV file.

Comment: I understand that.  This will correctly parse it.  Of course we'd like to have perfect input, but not everyone has access to the program that generates their input. Sometimes you have to deal with the garbage you're given.

Comment: In the comments on the question, the OP said that they thought the correctly-generated version had "too many `"`" (by what standard or measure, I can't say) and started removing them.